# Angular 4.x HTTP Client Error Handling

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5

I'm trying to develop an app that uses Angular on front and Laravel 5.0 at back.

In HTTP requests, I'm having a hard time getting errors.

This is my **MenuController.php** that gives my menus to **Angular** as **JSON**:

```
    if($control){
        $response->data = Menu::get()->toArray();
    }

    if(!$control) {
        $response->error = 'Error!';
    }

    return json_encode($response);
```

And this is my **menu.service.ts**:

```
private menusUrl = '/api/menu';

constructor (private http: Http) {}

getMenus(): Observable<Menu[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.menusUrl)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();

    return body.data || { };
}

private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;

    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    console.error(errMsg);

    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

And this is the **menu-index.component.ts**:

```
errorMessage: string;
menus: Menu[];
mode = 'Observable';

constructor(private menusService: MenusService) { }

ngOnInit() { this.getMenus(); }

getMenus() {
    this.menusService.getMenus()
        .subscribe(
            menus => this.menus = menus,
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

The part where I get my menus from Laravel works fine, but I couldn't get the error messages.

Hint: My Angular files are nearly exact copies of the ones that are presented in Angular HTTP Client tutorial. The main problem is how should I return my errors using Laravel so that Angular catches them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was not returning a proper error response. Here is the related part in the corrected version of **MenuController.php**:

```
if(!$control) {
    $response['error'] = 'ERROR!';

    return (new Response($response, 400))
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of things you can improve:

- You don't need to manually serialize your data carrier. Laravel handles that for you. All you need to do is `return $response`.
- Your handle error should return the error message. The way chained promises work is that the callback to invoke next receives the return value from the former. So I believe it should be sufficient to return `return errMsg`.

I do not know if these improvements would resolve your issue, but it is certainly one step in the debugging process.

Comment: Dear @Leonard, thank you for the serialization tip. However, your second tip didn't solve my problem.